# Azure SHIR could not connect to Azure data factory while registering with keys

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Self-Hosted Integration Runtime could not connect to Azure data factory while registering with keys Facing below error while registering keys with installed self hosted integration runtime

[image]

When I tried to install latest SHIR version, I'm getting the following error in registration step: "The Integration Runtime(Self-hosted)node has encountered an error during registration. Unable to determine the Integration Runtime node status. Confirm that the Integration Runtime Host Service is running, and a valid SSL certificate has been specified."

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to TCP settings. you need to open the server settings to the internet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/manage-integration-runtimes#networking-requirements

Similar thread : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1295905/purview-shir-registration-error